# Why is find_srid no longer immutable?

Tags: postgis, mapserver

I recently upgraded our PostgreSQL engine from 11 to 13 for one of our dbs and along with that, I upgraded PostGIS from 2.4 to 3.4.  We're using MapServer for one of our apps and it's generating queries like this:

```sql
select "sourceid"::text,
  "featuretyp"::text,
  "cartodb_id"::text,
  "name"::text,
  "sourcetype"::text,
  "drawingord"::text,
  "isnew"::text,
  ST_AsBinary(("geom"),'NDR') as geom,
  "cartodb_id"::text 
from my_table 
where "geom" && ST_GeomFromText(
  'POLYGON((-12068252.5062205 2978893.85839647,-12068252.5062205 4369793.96473184,-10212686.4400848 4369793.96473184,-10212686.4400848 2978893.85839647,-12068252.5062205 2978893.85839647))'
  ,find_srid('','my_table','geom')) 
and ("featuretyp"::text = 'polygon')
```

When running explain (analyze, buffers) on that query, it compiles the where clause into binary when using the old db and leaves it as text for the new.  This is apparently the case because Postgres can only do that when the functions are immutable.

Checking the definition of st_geomfromtext and find_srid, I learned that while the former remains immutable, find_srid no longer is.  The definition is the same with IMMUTABLE replaced with STABLE.  This has made my queries an order of magnitude slower.

Why did this change happen?  I couldn't find anything in the release notes.  Is there a new function that should be used instead of find_srid?  Is there any way to make MapServer use this?  Is there anyway to make hard code the SRID?  Btw, My .map files merely specify

geom from my_table

as the data source.

Comment: Do you have `using srid xxxx` in the DATA of your mapfile?

Comment: An `immutable` function is evaluated at planning time. If the plan is re-used (which is not guaranteed), the function won't be evaluated again. So if the SRID was changed after the plan was "cached", the wrong SRID would be returned, hence it is valid to flag the function as `stable` only, i.e. the output won't change during a single statement. That being said, you are free to override this

Comment: FWIW the change was from 5 years ago, see https://github.com/postgis/postgis/commit/3ddc11483b2266d3a914ecfdeb3e2a343e0f6dd4 and https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4344

Comment: @MikeT Not sure what you mean by "overriding".  Do you mean change the function definition?

Comment: @user30184, unfortunately, that seemed to have no effect.  FTR, I changed my code from 
LAYER
...
  DATA "geom from my_table"
...
END

to

LAYER
...
  DATA "geom FROM my_table using srid 3857"
...
END

Comment: The syntax is actually `...using srid=3857` but I believe that you have already found it from the documentation. I suppose that the data in the database table is really in EPSG:3857, that there is a corresponding line in the geometry_columns table, and that you have a PROJECTION block in your mapfile. If find_srid is still triggered I do not understand why.

Comment: overriding == change the function definition

Comment: The function https://postgis.net/docs/Find_SRID.html should be very fast because it is doing so simple thing from a table that is usually small. What I wonder is the next thing `and ("featuretyp"::text = 'polygon')`. Have you created the table so that it can hold all kind of geometries (generic GEOMETRY geometry type)? Do you have other geometry types (points, linestrings) in the table?

Comment: @user30184, yes, the geom column can hold points, lines, polygons and centroids.  The .map file has 4 layers, one for each.  There is indeed a projection block in the .map file which says

PROJECTION
     "init=epsg:3857"

I also changed the syntax.  Still no love.  I think find_srid is indeed fast, but because it can't preprocess the ST_GeomFromText line, the whole thing is slow.

Comment: I would make a test by creating separate tables for points, linestrings, and polygons. Just to be sure that the filter-by-geometry type is not the slow part. But the query is still rather simple. How many rows do you have in the table, and how long does it take to run the query?

Comment: 3479 rows.  It takes about 4 seconds to run the query for the polygons (which returns 3110 rows) on the new db.  It usually takes about 3 seconds on the old db.  MapServer generates 8 queries, two for each of the feature types using two different rectangles.  I have not been able to figure out where these two rectangles are coming from.  Running all 8 queries takes at least twice as long on the new db.  The polygons and centroids are the slowest.

Comment: That is ridiculously slow but I do not know your architecture and I cannot say why. I tested similar queries on my laptop and finding 1000 polygons out of 100000 and printing them on the console takes 50-100 milliseconds. Planning time without find_srid was only 1 ms slower than with find_srid.